# Finding the general equation for $3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+11\frac{dy}{dx}-7y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution for this but not sure if I'm going about it the correct way.

I know the following:

$y=e^rx$

$y'=re^{rx}$

$y''=r^2e^{rx}$

Applying this to $3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+11\frac{dy}{dx}-7y=0$ I get:

$3r^2e^{rx}+11re^{rx}-7e^{rx}$ and when factored I get $3r^2+11r-7=0$

As a solution I get:

$\frac{-11+\sqrt{205}}{6}$ and $\frac{-11-\sqrt{205}}{6}$

I'm confused as to where I go from here.  Any hints?

Comment: Where did that y come from? 3r2+11r−7=0, and you should know how to find the roots of that.

Comment: @DougM it was a typo, sorry about that!

Comment: The basic idea is to see what value of k you would need to make y=exp(kx) a solution. You find that k must satisfy a quadratic. So that gives you two possible values of k. Since the original equation is linear, linear combinations of solutions work.

Comment: Just write the solution.

Comment: $y=Ae^{r_1 x} + B e^{r_2 x}$

Comment: Is the solution I found correct? @kmitov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algebra is ok:

Solution is therefore:

$$ y(x) = Ae^{\frac{\sqrt{205}-11}{6}x} + Be^{\frac{-11 - \sqrt{205}}{6}x}$$